Inserting text in header using tikzpicture adds an a space

My MWE
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\NewDocumentCommand{\pageframeHeader}{O{0.75} O{gray} O{0pt}}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=#1, color=#2]
        \draw[line width=#3]
        (current page header area.north west)
        rectangle
        (current page header area.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{bophook}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\AtBeginPage{%
    \pageframeHeader
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    
    \node[anchor=base west] at(current page header area.south west){Prepared by: Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh, PhD};%
    
    \node[anchor=base west] at (current page header area.south west){\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}};%
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Try ,inner sep=0pt in your tikzpicture options because the nodes have a sep by default.

your definition of \pageframeHeader starts with a space before the tikzpicture.
